# Does anybody know what keeps Google from creating an Android native x86 emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

If you have ever developed apps for Apple iOS - you know that your app usually runs 1000 times  faster on the emulator than on an actual device. This is because the build in XCode is set up in such a way that it creates an i386-build of the app for native x86 emulator.
On the contrary Android emulator uses QEMU and takes naive approach to emulating the actual ARM-build of the OS. I think it would really speed up things if they created an x86 port of the emulator - especially taking into account that there is another virtualization layer - DalvikVM, which is the only thing to be ported - the apps will still get compiled into the same byte-code.

Maybe someone here has an in-depth explanation why is it so difficult to make a good-performing emulator so that the Android apps become testable in it?

Comment: I removed the link to the blog post and changed the description of the question for those of you who think that this is a "plug for another website". I would really like to hear some opinions on the matter instead of silent minuses. thanx

Answer (score 2):

The bad performance is caused by the software GL rendering. Google is working on it, so sooner or later there will be a smooth running emulator

Comment: I was more concerned with performance of some non-graphical tasks.  For example I have parsing going on that takes seconds on the emulator and milliseconds on the device.  Which is not an issue for the same iOS app running in iOS simulator.